# Angular - about making method contains subscribe()

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I want to ask about making method contains subscribe().
First code works now. but I think I don't want to write same code twice so I decided to make method.

I want to make method about this part.

```
this.tableService.getRowData(this.upperRowPath).subscribe((rowData) => {
        this.localStorageService
            .fetchColumns(this.userId, this.url, areaA)
            .subscribe((columnData) => {
                if (columnData && columnData.length > 0) {
                    this.tables.uppserTable = new TableSetting(
                        this.userId,
                        this.url,
                        areaA,
                        resizableColumnsA,
                        reorderableColumnsA,
                        columnData,
                        rowData,
                        paginatorA,
                        paginatorRowsA,
                        this.upperColumnPath
                    );
                } else {
                    this.tableService
                        .getColumnSetting(this.upperColumnPath)
                        .subscribe((initData) => {
                            this.tables.uppserTable = new TableSetting(
                                this.userId,
                                this.url,
                                areaA,
                                resizableColumnsA,
                                reorderableColumnsA,
                                initData,
                                rowData,
                                paginatorA,
                                paginatorRowsA,
                                this.upperColumnPath
                            );
                        });
                }
            });
    });
```

please look this code below. this code is inside of component and this ngOnInit() works now. I can see 2 Table  in view.

```
upper: TableSetting;
lower: TableSetting;
userId: string;
url: string;
area: string;
tables: TableInfo;    


ngOnInit() {

    this.tables = new TableInfo();

    this.userId = 'user01';

    this.url = this.router.url;

    const areaA = 'upper';
    const reorderableColumnsA = false;
    const resizableColumnsA = false;
    const paginatorA = true;
    const paginatorRowsA = 10;

    this.tableService.getRowData(this.upperRowPath).subscribe((rowData) => {
        this.localStorageService
            .fetchColumns(this.userId, this.url, areaA)
            .subscribe((columnData) => {
                if (columnData && columnData.length > 0) {
                    this.tables.uppserTable = new TableSetting(
                        this.userId,
                        this.url,
                        areaA,
                        resizableColumnsA,
                        reorderableColumnsA,
                        columnData,
                        rowData,
                        paginatorA,
                        paginatorRowsA,
                        this.upperColumnPath
                    );
                } else {
                    this.tableService
                        .getColumnSetting(this.upperColumnPath)
                        .subscribe((initData) => {
                            this.tables.uppserTable = new TableSetting(
                                this.userId,
                                this.url,
                                areaA,
                                resizableColumnsA,
                                reorderableColumnsA,
                                initData,
                                rowData,
                                paginatorA,
                                paginatorRowsA,
                                this.upperColumnPath
                            );
                        });
                }
            });
    });

    const areaB = 'lower';
    const reorderableColumnsB = true;
    const resizableColumnsB = true;
    const paginatorB = true;
    const paginatorRowsB = 10;

    this.tableService.getRowData(this.lowerRowPath).subscribe((rowData) => {
        this.localStorageService
        .fetchColumns(this.userId, this.url, areaB)
        .subscribe((columnData) => {
            if (columnData && columnData.length > 0) {
                this.tables.lowerTable = new TableSetting(
                    this.userId,
                    this.url,
                    areaB,
                    resizableColumnsB,
                    reorderableColumnsB,
                    columnData,
                    rowData,
                    paginatorB,
                    paginatorRowsB,
                    this.lowerColumnPath
                );
            } else {
                this.tableService
                    .getColumnSetting(this.lowerColumnPath)
                    .subscribe((initData) => {
                        this.tables.lowerTable = new TableSetting(
                            this.userId,
                            this.url,
                            areaB,
                            resizableColumnsB,
                            reorderableColumnsB,
                            initData,
                            rowData,
                            paginatorB,
                            paginatorRowsB,
                            this.lowerColumnPath
                        );
                    });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

this is html code.

```
<grid-serialize *ngIf="tables.uppserTable && tables.lowerTable" [tables]="tables"></grid-serialize>
```

I made method about duplicated code like this.
when I use this method, no error but table don't display in view.

```
makeTableData(area: string,
    rowPath: string,
    columnPath: string,
    resizableColumns: boolean,
    reorderableColumns: boolean,
    paginator: boolean,
    paginatorRows: number,
    tableSetting: TableSetting ) {

    this.tableService.getRowData(rowPath).subscribe((rowData) => {
        this.localStorageService
            .fetchColumns(this.userId, this.url, area)
            .subscribe((columnData) => {
                if (columnData && columnData.length > 0) {
                    tableSetting = new TableSetting(
                        this.userId,
                        this.url,
                        area,
                        resizableColumns,
                        reorderableColumns,
                        columnData,
                        rowData,
                        paginator,
                        paginatorRows,
                        columnPath
                    );
                } else {
                    this.tableService
                        .getColumnSetting(columnPath)
                        .subscribe((initData) => {
                            tableSetting = new TableSetting(
                                this.userId,
                                this.url,
                                area,
                                resizableColumns,
                                reorderableColumns,
                                initData,
                                rowData,
                                paginator,
                                paginatorRows,
                                columnPath
                            );
                        });
                }
            });
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.pattern = PanePattern.Vertical;
    this.mode = PaneMode.Search;

    this.tables = new TableInfo();

    this.userId = 'user01';

    this.url = this.router.url;

    const areaA = 'upper';
    const reorderableColumnsA = false;
    const resizableColumnsA = false;
    const paginatorA = true;
    const paginatorRowsA = 10;

    this.makeTableData(areaA,
        this.upperRowPath,
        this.upperColumnPath,
        resizableColumnsA,
        reorderableColumnsA,
        paginatorA,
        paginatorRowsA,
        this.tables.uppserTable );

   const areaB = 'lower';
    const reorderableColumnsB = true;
    const resizableColumnsB = true;
    const paginatorB = true;
    const paginatorRowsB = 10;

    this.makeTableData(areaB,
        this.lowerRowPath,
        this.lowerColumnPath,
        resizableColumnsB,
        reorderableColumnsB,
        paginatorB,
        paginatorRowsB,
        this.tables.lowerTable);
}
```

this is another method I thought, and this method return TableSetting object.
but this method doesn't work because of this error. 
"Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'TableSetting'.
  Property 'userId' is missing in type 'Subscription'."

Why this code has error?? I thought this method works.

```
makeTableDataB(area: string,
    rowPath: string,
    columnPath: string,
    resizableColumns: boolean,
    reorderableColumns: boolean,
    paginator: boolean,
    paginatorRows: number ): TableSetting {

    return this.tableService.getRowData(rowPath).subscribe((rowData) => {
        return this.localStorageService
            .fetchColumns(this.userId, this.url, area)
            .subscribe((columnData) => {
                if (columnData && columnData.length > 0) {
                    return new TableSetting(
                        this.userId,
                        this.url,
                        area,
                        resizableColumns,
                        reorderableColumns,
                        columnData,
                        rowData,
                        paginator,
                        paginatorRows,
                        columnPath
                    );
                } else {
                    return this.tableService
                        .getColumnSetting(columnPath)
                        .subscribe((initData) => {
                            return new TableSetting(
                                this.userId,
                                this.url,
                                area,
                                resizableColumns,
                                reorderableColumns,
                                initData,
                                rowData,
                                paginator,
                                paginatorRows,
                                columnPath
                            );
                        });
                }
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide a simpler example.

Comment: sorry for less infromation. I edited my question.